# Illustrator SVG unequal coordinate exporting for shape tween

Tags: svg, coordinates, adobe-illustrator, tween, smil

I am trying to create a SMIL animation tween between two shapes and I know that the two shapes need to have the same number of coordinates. The problem I have is when I export the two SVGs from Illustrator the coordinates do not match up in terms of how many sets there are. Both shapes are created form the same source with no extra points added or removed, just a curve at the top straightened out.

Here is my SVG on Codepen http://codepen.io/tands/pen/LEmoOK and below...

```
<!-- smile circle  -->

<svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 453.5 290" enable-background="new 0 0 453.5 290" xml:space="preserve">

<path fill="#000000" d="
                      M226.8,
                      34.9

                      C146.3,
                      34.9,
                      71.5,
                      22,
                      8.9,
                      0

                      C3.1,
                      20.1,
                      0,
                      41.3,
                      0,
                      63.2

                      C0,
                      188.5,
                      101.5,
                      290,
                      226.8,
                      290

                      S453.5,
                      188.5,
                      453.5,
                      63.2

                      c0-21.9-3.1-43.1-8.9-63.2

                      C382.1,
                      22,
                      307.2,
                      34.9,
                      226.8,
                      34.9z

                      H0z


                      "/>

 </svg>


 <!-- partial circle -->
 <svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 453.5 290" enable-background="new 0 0 453.5 290" xml:space="preserve">

 <path fill="#000000" d="
                      M8.9,
                      0

                                C3.1,
                                20.1,
                                0,
                                41.3,
                                0,
                                63.2

                      C3.1,
                      20.1,
                      0,
                      41.3,
                      0,
                      63.2

                      C0,
                      188.5,
                      101.5,
                      290,
                      226.8,
                      290

                      S453.5,
                      188.5,
                      453.5,
                      63.2

                      c0-21.9-3.1-43.1-8.9-63.2

                              C0,
                              0,
                              0,
                              0,
                              0,
                              0

                      H8.9z

                      "/>

</svg>
```

So I guess my question is how do I achieve the shape tween between the two shapes on codepen even though they have different coordinates?

Comment: What's your question? If it's about how to use Illustrator that's off topic for StackOverflow as it's not a programming question.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a Illustrator issue or if there is another way of achieving the desired results outside of illustrator, so until I find the solution I won't know :(

Comment: So I guess my question is how do I achieve the shape tween between the two shapes on codepen even though they have different coordinates?

Comment: You don't. You alter the shapes so they have the same coordinates.

Comment: Thats what I thought, but how do I make the second shape have the same coordinates whilst maintaining its shape?

Comment: I think you need to read a tutorial about what the path commands mean. For instance you can use a C to draw a straight line if you make the control points degenerate.

Comment: Thanks Robert, i'll do some research :)

Comment: OK i got the same number of points, what would be the best way to tween between the two shapes? shall i start a new post? http://codepen.io/tands/pen/LEmoOK